# Swift return types

Tags: swift, types, ios8, return

I have these two classes: Foo and Bar.
Foo has an initialiser and a constructor function called `makeObject`. Bar extends Foo so, it inherits the `makeObject` function too. I know that using `self` as the return type of `makeObject` is not correct, but i didn't know how to set it to return a Bar instance and not a Foo one.

```
class Foo{
   var x
   init(x:Int){
     self.x = x
   }

   class func makeObject(x:Int)->self{
      return self(generateRandomNumber())
   }

   class func generateRandomNumber()->Int{
     //...
   }
}

class Bar:Foo{
  //...
}


let fb = Bar.makeObject()
println(fb) // would return a Foo instance
```

Comment: Should i use `class func makeObject(x:Int)->Foo` as a return type and make a cast `Bar.makeObject() as Bar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the return type as `Self`. This in turn requires that
the init method is marked as `required init`:

```
class Foo {
    var x : Int

    required init(x : Int) {
        self.x = x
    }

    class func makeObject() -> Self {
        return self(x: generateRandomNumber())
    }

    class func generateRandomNumber() -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(100))
    }

    func whatAmI() -> String {
        return "I am a Foo"
    }
}

class Bar:Foo {
    override func whatAmI() -> String {
        return "I am a Bar"
    }
}

let fb = Bar.makeObject()
println(fb.whatAmI()) // "I am a Bar"
```

Option-click on `fb` in Xcode also reveals that the type is correctly 
inferred as `Bar`.

Comment: Stupid me, i wronte self with a lower case and got an error :)) Never thought of uppercasing it :D

Answer (score 0):

You will want to override the makeobject method in your subclass (bar) and return the correct type.

Simply repeat the function def utilizing the overrides keyword, and accessing base methods using super.whatever

Comment: I would like not to override it. Read my comment to the question. Would it work?

Comment: No. You cannot cast from a base type to a subclass in OO. Any properties or data that make up the subclass would be missing...

Comment: Downcasting is allowed in Swift, but i would need to use a `as?` in case something goes wrong.

Comment: You can downcast when the underlying type is actually bar. But if it was created as foo it is always a foo.